# Discrete random vector and their sum

Tags: probability

> Given the random vector $(X,Y)$ with joint probability $P(0,1)=\frac{1}{18}$, $P(1,2)=\frac{3}{18}$, $P(1,4)=\frac{5}{18}$, $P(2,0)=\frac{2}{18}$, $P(2,1)=\frac{4}{18}$, $P(2,3)=\frac{3}{18}$ and $0$ otherwise, I need to find:

1. Domain, probability and distribution for $(Y|X=2)$
2. Domain and probability for $Z=X+Y$

1) I need to find the marginal $p_X$ for $X$ as:

$p_X(2)=\sum_yp(2,y)=\frac{2}{18}+\frac{4}{18}+\frac{3}{18}=\frac{9}{18}$

Now I can calcolate che conditional $(Y|X=2)$

$p_{Y|X}(2,0)=\frac{p(2,0)}{p_X(2)}=\frac{2}{9}$

$p_{Y|X}(2,1)=\frac{p(2,1)}{p_X(2)}=\frac{4}{9}$

$p_{Y|X}(2,3)=\frac{p(2,3)}{p_X(2)}=\frac{3}{9}$

2) I read that $p_Z(z)=\sum_{x}p(x,z-x)$, but I don't know how to proceed. And suggestion?

Comment: For 2), don't worry for now about the "convolution" expression. Just make a table of possible values of $X+Y$, and the associated probabilities. For example, $X+Y$ can be $5$ in two ways, $(1,4)$ and $(2,3)$. So $\Pr(X+Y=5)=5/18+3/18$.  Most of the rest is simpler, for example $\Pr(X+Y=1)=1/18$.

Comment: I made the math and get this: $P(Z=0)=0$, $P(Z=1)=\frac{1}{18}$, $P(Z=2)=\frac{2}{18}$, $P(Z=3)=\frac{3}{18}+\frac{4}{18}=\frac{7}{18}$, $P(Z=4)=0$, $P(Z=5)=\frac{3}{18}+\frac{5}{18}=\frac{7}{18}$ and $P(Z=6)=0$.
How could I use the convolution to solve this?

Comment: Don't mention the probabilities when they are $0$. That will remove $3$ of your entries. Convolution here would just make things look more complicated, they take care of determining when you need to add things together, as you did for $3$ and $5$.